# Launch application from URI - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, url, uri, protocols, roblox

I have tried to create a protocol for my application to launch a game, but I seem to be having trouble actually launching it from a URI. The protocol I'm trying to use is `roblox://` but if I type it in, it doesn't seem to launch the application, Windows tells me it can't find an app to launch the URL.

The code I used is:

```
If (My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator)) Then
    Dim newRegKey As RegistryKey
    newRegKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("RobloxProtocol", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
    newRegKey.SetValue("", "URL:roblox")
    newRegKey.SetValue("URL Protocol", "")
    Dim newRegCom As RegistryKey
    newRegCom = newRegKey.CreateSubKey("shell\open\command")
    newRegCom.SetValue("", """" & Application.ExecutablePath & """" & " -id " & """" & "%1" & """")

    warnText.Text = "ROBLOX Protocol Launcher is installed!"
Else
    warnText.Text = "Please run ROBLOX Protocol Launcher as Administrator to finish the install process."
End If
```

If I look in the Registry using `regedit`, the keys are there (the ones I registered were the ones from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), it just doesn't seem to be launching. I tried after restarting my computer and it still doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article you reference, the subkey name was `alert` under HKCR, where the url to launch from is `alert://...`.

Change your subkey to `roblox` instead of `RobloxProtocol` (or try launching from `robloxprotocol://`

Comment: @celliott1997: No problems.